# Changing select element depend on window width using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, resize, window, width

i found out that when my windows is less than `936` px,my div with the selectors looses is center ability,because the width of the selectors. i tried solving this using css`(width:100%)`,but it didnt work. so now im trying jquery solution.
i made some calculation and i found out that for every window width who is less than 936 , i need to change the size of the selector to : `3*window_width -2578`
so i used this :

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() < 936)
    {
        size = (3*$( window ).width()-2578);
  $( '"select"' ).css('width', 'size'+'px');;

  }
});
```

but it dosent change the selectors width.. why?

jsfiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tkt4mfwx/1/)

Comment: I can be completely of here, but the selector should be `$('select')` and the css function should be `.css('width', size+'px');` since you are using the variable size. And to be correct JS you should also have `var size = ...` if you don't declare it earlier

Answer (score 0):

Because size is a variable, not a string.

So change

```
$( '"select"' ).css('width', 'size'+'px');;
```

To this

```
$( "select" ).css('width', size+'px');
```

Here's a "working" fiddle. Although it doesn't actually work because your calculation is resulting in a negative amount of pixels. So you'll have to redo your logic about that.
http://jsfiddle.net/tkt4mfwx/3/